# Convert post.get('href') to text or string form, Excel can not handle hyperlinks over 255 characters

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, href

When I write URLs to Excel (from a Python script), any over 255 characters are not written. But I don't actually need the URL to have a hyperlink attached to it.

For example I need 'www.ebay.co.uk' but I do not need '[www.ebay.co.uk](http://www.ebay.co.uk)'. As long as I  have the text, then the next part of my script will work fine.

I tried str() and .text but had no luck with either

**str()**

```
if (post.get('title'))!=None:
   df1.loc[Row] = [str((post.get('href'))),Row]
   Row = Row + 1
```

**.text**

```
if (post.get('title'))!=None:
    df1.loc[Row] = [(post.get('href')).text,Row]
    Row = Row + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.ExcelWriter` has an `options` parameter that you can combine with `xlsxwriter` engine to prevent string-to-URL conversion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data': [
        'http://www.python.org/',
        'http://' + 'a'*250,
    ]
})

with pd.ExcelWriter('0.xlsx',
                    engine='xlsxwriter',
                    options={'strings_to_urls': False}) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

[image: links as strings]

**Source**: [XlsxWriter Docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas)